# How do I get mod-rewrite to access the proper directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod-rewrite to eliminate urls like {root}/index.php?action=about&page=faq.  I want {root}/about/faq to redirect to the php url.  My .htaccess file looks like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(index|about|calendar|news|contact)$ index.php?action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(index|about)/(.+)$ index.php?action=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

When redirecting to index.php?action=$1, this works fine.  However, it doesn't work completely when the second rule is used.  The html content appears fine, but the stylesheet and images are missing.  The page seems to think that it's in a subdirectory.  So {root}/about/faq looks for images in the folder about/images, instead of in the images folder found at the root.  The PHP script says that the working directory is still the root directory, however.  How do I make the pages think that they are in the root directory?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteRule ^(index|about|calendar|news|contact)/(.*)/$ /index.php?action=$1&page=$2
```

Would result in /about/faq/ rewriting to index.php?action=about&page=faq

/calendar/month/  would result in index.php?action=calendar&page=month

Also unless you want to rewrite imagesfiles I would add:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$ [NC]
```

This will stop image requests being rewritten.